# How do I use the Eclipse debugger in an AsyncTask when developing for Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-asynctask, adt

I'm running ADT (Android Development Tools) in Eclipse and verified that my debugger is working by putting a breakpoint in `MainMenu.oncreate (class Activity)`. But when I put it in the first line of my `AsyncTask.doInBackground`, it never hits it. I know it's running because I put a Log statement in the `AsyncTask` and it shows up in LogCat. Any help would be appreciated as I prefer the debugger over the logging.

My versions:

```
Eclipse SDK Version: 3.6.1  
Build id: M20100909-0800
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have debugging=True in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, I did <manifest android:debuggable="true"> in the AndroidManifest.xml. Thanks

Comment: I just discovered that if I put some `Log.d()` within `doInBackground()` that the debugger suddenly starts hitting breakpoints !!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Put the following code fragment in the beginning of `doInBackground`:

`android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();`

Then when you set a breakpoint in that thread, eclipse will find it.

Comment: As a note, when **not** debugging I had to comment this line out in order for it to run.

Comment: I can see that this is clearly the method to be able to do this, but I am not managing to hit the breakpoints even after putting this at the beginning of doInBackground. Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 9):

in addition to sargas's answer , because in Run mode you could get an error if you forget to comment that line, you could use the following:

```
if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected())
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

so it takes care of itself.